# What's the difference between {∅} ⊆ {{∅}, 1} and {{∅}} ⊆ {{∅}, 1}?

Tags: elementary-set-theory

I'm struggling to understand what the double {{}} means

Comment: There are so so many questions on this site about sets of sets of sets, sets of empty sets, which are subsets of what, etc.

Answer (score 1):

The first is false (because $\emptyset$ is not an element of $\{\{\emptyset\},1\}$); the second is true. The double $\{\{\emptyset\}\}$ means "the set containing the set containing the empty set".

Answer (score 0):

$\emptyset$ is the set with no elements, $\{\emptyset\}$ is the set whose only element is the set with no elements, and $\{\{\emptyset\}\}$ is the set whose only element is the set whose only element is the set with no elements, so $\{\emptyset\}\in \{\{\emptyset\}\}$ as an element

Answer (score 0):

$\{...\}$ means the set whose members are all those and only those things that are equal to anything named, listed, described, or defined by the "$...$".

$\{\emptyset\}$ is the set whose sole member is $\emptyset$.

If the "$...$" is "$\{\emptyset\}$" then we have $\{\{\emptyset\}\}$ which is a set whose sole member is $\{\emptyset\}$.

Some beginners have difficulty in accepting that a set may be a member of another set